# A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 17289

Tags: android, error-handling, sdk, barcode-scanner, honeywell

I have used Honeywell SDK for scanning the barcode. I have implemented the sdk but while opening the app, I'm getting the following error.

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 17289
```

Help, please

Thanks in advance